# How to click on a javascript link on Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to create an automated login system on Python using Selenium but I can't seem to be able to click on the "Login" button which uses a javascript code to send the login details.

Could someone let me know how I might be able to send the login details filled in by clicking on the "Login" button (more of a link it seems)?

The following is the div including the "Login" button.

```html
<div class="btn-login">
<p>
<a href="javascript:cmdButton_push(document.MypageLoginActionForm);">Login</a>
</p>
</div>
```

XPATH:

```
//*[@id="login-form"]/div[1]/p/a
```

I've tried:

1. click by finding the XPATH
2. click by finding the text "Login"
   and neither have worked.

Please let me know should you have any questions.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where's the element with id="login-form"?

Comment: Post the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **Login** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `link_text`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_link_text("Login").click()
  ```
- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.btn-login>p>a[href*='MypageLoginActionForm']").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='btn-login']/p/a[contains(@href, 'MypageLoginActionForm') and text()='Login']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Login"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.btn-login>p>a[href*='MypageLoginActionForm']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='btn-login']/p/a[contains(@href, 'MypageLoginActionForm') and text()='Login']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```